# Como usar uglifyjs con clases?

Tags: javascript, es6

He escrito una libreria llamada joe.js la cual contiene algunas funciones y dos clases. El problema viene cuando trato de utilizar el comando uglifyjs

```
uglifyjs joe.pretty.js --compress --mangle > joe.js
```

la cual me devuelve el error:

```
Parse error at joe.pretty.js:6,6
Unexpected token: name (Dice) 
Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:196:18                                                                                                                               )
at js_error (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:204:11)
at croak (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:663:9)
at token_error (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:671:9)
at unexpected (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:677:9)
at semicolon (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:697:43)
at simple_statement (/usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:871:73)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:744:19
at /usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:710:24
at /usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js@2/lib/parse.js:1445:23
```

Lo cual es porque tengo una clase llamada `dice` la cual no reconoce.
¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Si estás usando ES6 (y las clases son ES6), Uglify no te va a aceptar tal cosa. Tendrías que pasar por Babel para transformar tu código a ES5 y luego aplicar Uglify sobre la salida. Esto se podría hacer usando por ejemplo la librería Rollup.js  con los plugins para babel y uglify en el flujo